# Enabling Solr to retrieve documents using queries with trailing characters

Tags: search, solr

How can I retrieve documents using queries with trailing characters in Solr? For instance, when querying `q=entry:bookasd`, I want to retrieve documents where the `entry` field contains values such as `book`, `boo`, `bo`, and `b` (supposing that they are actually exist and `booka`, `bookas`, etc. doesn't)
I have tried to use NGram Tokenizer but of course it only returns the documents if the query is shorter or equal to than the documents field value. I want it to return the documents even if the query has trailing characters in it.